# SQL Text Processing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2

I am researching large scale text processing capabilities of Microsoft SQL Server (version 2008 R2). We are in the process of implementing a large database that stores documents (text). We need to produce effective search results based on the text stored in the table(s). Here is an article that caught my attention and am wondering if anyone has actually implemented this:

http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/31339/1954?pf=true

If you have either implemented this or anything similar to this or even any other text processing algorithms, please respond.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The article that you linked to doesn't really cover searching text per se, although it does provide methods for doing text processing. It's not entierly clear from the question exactly what you're trying to do, but I'm assuming you need to implement search engine type functionality, where you return the most relevant results based on search text. If that is the case and you have to implement something solely in SQL Server, you'll probably want to look into [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

That being said, I highly recommend that you look into utilizing [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) (which utilizes the Apache Lucene search library) for returning effective search results. [StackOverflow uses Lucene.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/) for its search functionality, and there is a lengthy discussion at the end of that last link on the pros and cons of using Lucene.NET or Solr. I've used Solr and IMHO it's far easier to work with and yields much better results than SQL Server with full text indexing. If you really want effective search in SQL Server, you're probably going to wind up building most of what is already in Lucene anyway, so it's probably easier to go with Lucene.NET or Solr.